# How do I write tests for Meteor which involves templating?

Tags: meteor, integration-testing, functional-testing, meteor-blaze, tinytest

I recently created a Meteor package and want to write some tests. What my test package basically do is that users can insert into the template `{{> abc}}` and they'll get an HTML element printed on the page.

With TinyTest, all you can do is test the package's API using something like `test.equal(actual, expected, message, not)`. However, I need it to test whether the element was successfully printed on the page. Furthermore, I will pass the template some parameters and test them too.

It seems like I'd have to create a dummy app, ***run bash*** to initiate the app, and test whether the elements can be found on page. **So should I only use TinyTest to test the API, and write my own tests (somehow!) for templating? If not, how should I go about it?**

I read something about `Blaze.toHTML`, but I cannot find anything in the [documentation](http://meteor.github.io/blaze/docs.html) on it? Nor it's [source page](https://github.com/meteor/blaze/search?q=toHTML).

Comment: FYI, [here's the doc for `Blaze.toHTML`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_tohtml). What you looked at is the documentation for the standalone Blaze project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **TinyTest** is great for starting with Unit testing, but what you need sounds more like an Integration test.

I would recommend you look into the following links for more info on testing with Meteor, especially with Velocity - Meteor's official testing framework:

- **[Announcing Velocity: the official testing framework for Meteor applications](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/07/14/meteor-testing-framework-velocity)**
- **[Velocity](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity)**
- **[The Meteor Testing Manual](http://www.meteortesting.com/)**

You can create a demo application, and run integration tests using Mocha or Jasmine.

Comment: Thanks for your correction, all these testing terms are making me dizzy, I'm checking Velocity out right now! @_@

Comment: Thanks for the links, so now, I'm using TinyTest to unit test my package, and created an example directory, inside of which I created a test application, and inside that application I am using `mike:mocha` for integration testing.